# Method to update the html file without refreshing the page every time

Tags: angular, frontend, page-refresh, getmethod

In my angular project have to code a shop-website. There is a Function where a product must first be accepted by a admin before showing in the shop itself. I have now implemented a component called "production authorization" where the admin can accept or reject a product. For that I get the products to be accepted with a get method with the link: "environment.endpointURL + 'products/authorized/no". after accepting it I update the project from authorized: 'no' to 'yes' so it won't be in the get method anymore (because the link changed to 'yes' at the end. But I have to refresh the page every time so it really doesn't show anymore in the 'product authorization' component. How can I implement it without having to refresh the page?

this is my .ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-authorization',
  templateUrl: './product-authorization.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-authorization.component.css']
})
export class ProductAuthorizationComponent implements OnInit {

  isAdmin: boolean;

  products: Product[];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'location', 'delivarable', 'description', 'price', 'acceptorreject'];


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }



  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getProducts()
  }

  getProducts(){
    return this.httpClient.get(environment.endpointURL + 'products/authorized/no').subscribe((res: any) =>
    {
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res;
    })
  }

  authorizeProduct(product: Product){
    product.authorized = "yes"
    product.status = "available"


    return this.httpClient.put(environment.endpointURL + 'products/' + product.productId, product ).subscribe((res: any) =>
    {
      console.log("Update:");
      console.log(res);

      //refresh page to update table
      this.refresh()

    })


  }

  rejectProduct(productId: number){
    return this.httpClient.delete(environment.endpointURL + 'products/' + productId).subscribe((res: any) =>
    {
      console.log("Delete:");

      //refresh page to update table
      this.refresh()
    })
  }

  refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }

}
```

and this is my .html file

```
<h3>Products to be authorized:</h3>

<table
mat-table [dataSource]="products" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.location}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="delivarable">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delivarable </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.delivarable}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="acceptorreject">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Authorize </th>
    <td mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="authorizeProduct(element)">Accept</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="rejectProduct(element.productId)">Reject</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the accepted object from your local products array in your authorizeProduct method and maybe in your rejectProduct method. With the Angular refresh cycle your ui should be updated afterwards.

Comment: I now removed the accepted and rejected objects from my local products array with `this.products.splice(this.products.indexOf(product),1)`. But I still don't know how I have to implement the refresh cycle? could you help me with that?